# Problemas com o método .getDownloadUrl( );

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Estou tendo problema em atualizar o método .getDownloadUrl( ); do firebase, estou tentando salvar uma imagem no Storege e lego apos pegar a url e salvar como uma caminho no DataBase.

```
 private void publicarPostagem(){

    final Postagem postagem = new Postagem();
    postagem.setIdUsuario(idUsuarioLogado);
    postagem.setDescricao(textDescricaoFiltro.getText().toString());

    //Recuperar dados da imagem para o firebase
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    imagem.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, baos);
    byte[] dadosImagem = baos.toByteArray();

    //Salvar imagem no Stogere
    StorageReference storageRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseStorage();
    StorageReference imagemRef = storageRef
            .child("imagens")
            .child("postagens")
            .child( postagem.getId() + ".jpeg");

    UploadTask uploadTask = imagemRef.putBytes( dadosImagem );
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(FiltroActivity.this,
                    "Erro ao salvar a imagem, tente novamente!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {



            //Recuperar local da foto
            Task<Uri> url = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl( );
            postagem.setCaminhoFoto(url.toString());
            Log.i("postagem", "url:" + postagem.getCaminhoFoto());
            /*
            * Tentei ressolver assim mas não consigo recuperar a url da imagem
            *
            *
            * */


            //Salvar postagem
            if( postagem.salvar() ){
                Toast.makeText(FiltroActivity.this,
                        "Sucesso ao salvar postagem!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                finish();
            }

        }
    });


}
```

Utilizando esse codigo tenho uma error no

```
 //Recuperar local da foto
            Uri url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            postagem.setCaminhoFoto( url.toString() );
```

Tentei utilizar este metodo

```
//Recuperar local da foto
            Task<Uri> url = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl( );
            postagem.setCaminhoFoto(url.toString());
```

Ja utilizando esse metodo eu não consigo recuperar a url verdadeira da imagem.

[image: Queria obter essa url]

Mas estou salvando essa no firebase

[image: No firebase esta salvado esta url, que não é a verdadeira OSB: isso acontece utilizando o método TASK]

Answer (score 0):

```
//Resolveu o problema
            Task<Uri> url = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
            while (!url.isSuccessful());
            Uri X = url.getResult();
            postagem.setCaminhoFoto(X.toString());
            Log.i("postagem", "url:" + postagem.getCaminhoFoto());
```

Resolveu o problema